# GIT system, branching and merging stuff - useful resources

Tags: git, bitbucket, branching-and-merging

Could you please advise me on good resources regarding the common learning of git system and branches. I am fresh with VCS, so I need to understand how branches and merging stuff work.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Here are a couple of links:
[1](https://try.github.io/) and
[2](https://learngitbranching.js.org/). 
Good luck and have fun! ;)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Addition to @alexandrum answer. Try to read git documentation, it is pretty good.